# How can I set up my game to accept either a boolean or an int at the same time

Tags: java

Inside of the while loop, I try to set up purchase as an option to use as an input storage device and turn into a choice from among purchasable options.

I would like to know if it is possible, and if so, how, to accept either a boolean or an integer at the same time, depending on whether the user would like to increase pageAmount, or buy an upgrade.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BookieClickerV1
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    double pageAmount = 0;
    int penNumber = 0;
    int scribeNumber = 0;
    int printingNumber = 0;
    int printerNumber = 0;
    int conwayNumber = 0;
    int mageNumber = 0;
    boolean gameStarted = true;
    boolean click = false;
    int purchase = 0;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to Bookie Clicker V1.0.");
        System.out.println("As this is the first version of the game, it can        be rather buggy");
        System.out.println("When you are ready to begin, type 'True' to represent a click.");
        System.out.println("Use the reference handed to you to know what you're purchasing.");

    while (gameStarted = true)
    {
        click = reader.nextBoolean();


            if (purchase == 1)
            {
                pageAmount -= Math.pow(15, (1.2 * (penNumber + 1)));
                penNumber += 1;
                purchase = 0;
            }
            if (purchase == 2)
            {
                pageAmount -= Math.pow(100, (1.2 * (scribeNumber + 1)));
                scribeNumber += 1;
                purchase = 0;
            }
            if (click == true)
            {
                if (penNumber > 0)
                {
                    pageAmount++;
                }


                pageAmount++;
                click = false;
                System.out.println("Your total number of pages written is "       + pageAmount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Daylen, please check through the answers when you can and select the one that fits what you need and works.

Comment: Cmon daylen. I don't mean to pester u, but you need to pick a solution.

Comment: wow. you havent been on since you posted the question. you must have found your answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You could accept an entire line, and then see whether it's an integer. Something like this:

```
String line = reader.nextLine();
try {
    int purchase = Integer.parseInt(line);
    // ...
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Just use .equals() if you want it to be case-sensitive.
    if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("True" /* or "Click", etc. */)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

Also note that you have a bug in your line

```
while (gameStarted = true)
```

which makes the while loop infinite (since `=` sets the `gameStarted` variable to `true`, causing the loop never to end). It should be

```
while (gameStarted == true)
```

or just

```
while (gameStarted)
```

Comment: I am just curious...checking the user input like this does make sense to me but then are you suggesting putting the entire block of code starting while(gameStarted==true) in the catch block?

Comment: @Doorknob you can go ahead and delete your comment. i will clear this one once you have.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is not the most efficient solution, and certainly not the most sophisticated as I have only been learning Java for two years at my high school, so no fancy methods or special stuff.

You could use a code block like this:

```
String a = scanner.next();//store input, makes it easier to manipulate
if(a.startsWith("T") || a.startsWith("F"))//this assumes the user enters true/false as an input
{
     //execute correct code, you could set a boolean true, execute a method
     //or whatever else you wanted to do
}

else
{
    int upgradeInt = Integer.parseInt(a);//you need this to get the 
    //input converted into an int. This is an edit, I forgot this step.      
    //executes correct code and can use String a to pass an upgrade or 
    //however you need your code to run
}
```

This is how I would do it because I am not fancy, but I am not confident this is the most efficient or most correct way to solve your problem. And, as Doorknob pointed out, the condition for your `while - loop` should not have a single `=`, but should have a `==` as this is the proper way to compare primitive data such as booleans. In the case that you have, you are setting a boolean to a certain value which would, in this case, put you into an infinite loop.

Comment: What if user enters "Test" as his input string?

Comment: @SaurabhJinturkar Two things: 1) Why would he be entering "Test" in light of the information in the question? The user will be entering, I assume, a number for an upgrade and "True" / "False" for increasing `pageAmount`. 2) This is just an example. The logic is valid. All the OP has to do is adapt the logic to fit the exact terms that the user will be allowed to enter.